# Solving linear programming question with one constraint where constraint is same formula as objective function

Tags: linear-programming, convex-hulls

[image: Image for visualization]

I recently came across this variation of linear programming problem where given a set of $2$-D points, we would like to find 1 point which maximizes certain objective function. Let's say the objective function is to maximize $y = m(x+A) + B$ where $m$ is gradient, $A$ and $B$ are constants. In the example above for simplicity, assume our objective function is $y=x$.

Now the constraints for our solution are

$x > 0$, $y > 0$, $y -m(X+A) - B \ge 0 $. Essentially saying that, our solution has to be in the first quadrant, while also located in the *upper* part of the objective function line itself.

My observation says that the solution has to be one of the corner points (convex hull) of our set of 2-D points (input) no matter what. Empirically, I ran some simulations and the results agreed. But, is there a more formal way to verify this?

Comment: Maximizing $m(x+A)+B$ is the same as maximizing $sign(m)x$, so it will be either the rightmost or leftmost point depending on the sign of $m$?

Comment: The extrema of a linear function on a convex set with polygonal boundary will always occur at vertices of a boundary. If you are looking for the maximum over a finite set of points, the convex hull of those points will be a convex set with polygonal boundary, with certain points of the set being the vertices. The maximum of the function over the convex hull (which includes all your points) will be one of the vertices, and therefore one of the points in your set. So yes, your observation is correct and formally provable.